# Does Safari's 'Export as PDF' keep JavaScript and allows data from external sources?

Tags: macos, ios, safari, pdf

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/893092/can-pdfs-contain-resources-that-are-loaded-from-the-internet), PDF files may contain executable behavior such as JavaScript, filesystem access, loading external (or local) resources, etc.

In macOS (but also interesting for iOS), I'd love to know whether the generated **output file of Safari when clicking 'Export as PDF...' may contain such "risky" or non-independent components**?

My goal is to create a PDF of the webpage, which will be totally reliable as similar the original website, but will work offline, and without dependency on any external file or web-server. In addition, I don't want the PDF file to access anything in my computer (filesystem, system-calls, information, fonts, packages, events or processes, etc). Does it guaranteed somewhere? If not, how can I guarantee that? (both the security and similarity aspects)

In addition, I saw another PDF-related feature in Safari, 'Print -> Save as PDF' which seems to produce a pretty similar output (based on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135806/difference-between-export-pdf-and-print-to-pdf-in-safari), it actually do slightly different thing under the hood). So, I'd love to get answers to my question, relating to this alternative as well.

P.S. It's also interesting to know whether any limitation on code execution within PDF is due to the format specification, or the filters Safari apply on the generated file, or maybe even the PDF reader app (eg Preview app in the case of macOS).

Answer (score 1):

Safari's Export As PDF uses macOS's Quartz engine to create a PDF 'version' of the ***rendered*** webpage. So no 'code' that's in the HTML gets transferred to the PDF.

In the same way, embedded video and audio in the webpage don't get embedded into the PDF -- you just get a still image of the video.

Adobe Acrobat provides methods for embedding JavaScript, video and other content into a PDF document; and the PDF specification documents it: but macOS's PDFs are purely graphical and there's no mechanism (that I can find) in the PDFKit API for embedding or viewing additional content, nor for accessing the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose to Export PDF then links will continue working as interactive elements, but the page is not dynamic. Hover effects and buttons like (on this page) "Ask a Question" don't do anything. Additionally, you can use a network traffic tool to confirm nothing is loaded dynamically. PDFs saved from Safari do not show any indication of being fancy.

When you choose Print > Save as PDF, the page may look different since many pages come with print-specific styling to make printouts easier to work with. For example, on this page the sidebars and toolbar are not included in the printout (among other changes).